# Generic: why use "class A <E extends Superclass>" in stead of "class B<Superclass>"?

Tags: java, generics

I am experimenting with Java generics. I understand with Java generics we can create class and methods which only deals with specific types. This enable detection of programming error at compile time.

My question may sounds strange.  Why use `E extends Superclass` instead of `Superclass`? Please take a look at the code below.

```
class Hunter <E extends Animal>{}

class Keaper <Animal>{}
    /*edit: as AR.3 and other pointed out, Keaper<Animal> is the same as Keaper<E>.
 Animal  is just a type parameter here*/

class Animal{}

class Cat extends Animal{}

class Dog extends Animal{}


public class TestGeneric {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hunter<Cat> hunter1 = new Hunter<>();
        Hunter<Dog> hunter2 = new Hunter<>();
        Hunter<Animal> hunter3 = new Hunter<>();

        ArrayList<Hunter> hunters=  new ArrayList<>();
        hunters.add(hunter1);
        hunters.add(hunter2);
        hunters.add(hunter3);

        Keaper<Cat> keaper1 = new Keaper<>();
        Keaper<Dog> keaper2 = new Keaper<>();
        Keaper<Animal> keaper3 = new Keaper<>();
//Edit: as AR.3 and others pointed out, Keaper<String> is also legal here.

        ArrayList<Keaper> keapers=  new ArrayList<>();
        keapers.add(keaper1);
        keapers.add(keaper2);
        keapers.add(keaper3);
    }
}
```

I feel `E extends Animal` is almost the same as `Animal`, except the first one may provide more information. Any idea?

Comment: What do you think `class Keaper <Animal>{}` does?

Comment: I think your using the word "Superclass" in both definitions is confusing because it conceals the different meaning of both definitions. `class B<Superclass>` is equivalent to `class B<E>`, where `E` is permitted to be any type without restriction. The name "Superclass" in this case has no meaning or effect, as names never do. It's just a name.

Comment: @Radiodef I thought class Keaper<Animal> is the same as class Keaper<E extends Animal>. I was wrong. Animal here is just a generic type parameter, like E or T.

Comment: @Norman you are right, thank you for clearing things up.

Comment: Just to add another comment from looking at your code: your keepers are declared as raw, non generic types in your lists. What you most likely want is ArrayList<Keeper<Animal>> or ArrayList<Keeper<? extends Animal>>. Otherwise your type info is lost as soon as you put those keepers in the list, in practice what you'll implicitly end up having is a list of Keeper<Object>. Your compiler most likely produced a warning about using a raw type.

Comment: @JHH Nice catch. Updated my answer with your comment.

Answer (score 15):

Actually `Animal` as declared in the definition of the `Keaper` class is nothing but a *type parameter* (it would be more conventional to just use one letter for it, like `Keaper<T>`). So it's a completely different range of possible type arguments: the `Keaper` class can accept any type as parameter, not just `Animal`s. You can write `Keaper<String>` and it will compile fine, which is clearly not what you want.

What you intended to do is not possible with generics: you cannot force a class to be generic with only one possible type argument ever associated with it. What you can do is limit the range of associated types to be, for example, any type that extends a certain type, which you already did with the `Hunter` class.

Also as mentioned in @JHH's comment, you should avoid using `Keaper` as a raw type in a list, otherwise the code would not be fully generic. Instead of `ArrayList<Keaper> keapers = new ArrayList<>()` you can write `ArrayList<Keaper<? extends Animal>> keapers = new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: this is a great answer. My mistake was I thought Keaper<Animal> is identical with Keaper<E extends Animal>. Actually Keaper<Animal> equals to Keaper<E>.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10):

Usually you would use `extends` when you want to keep the specific type of the in-parameter. Consider this example:

```
public class TestGeneric {

    public static <T extends Animal> T changeExtendedAnimal(T extendedAnimal) {
        return extendedAnimal;
    }

    public static Animal changeAnimal(Animal animal) {
        return animal;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Cat changedCat1 = changeExtendedAnimal(new Cat()); //Compiles fine. 
        Cat changedCat2 = changeAnimal(new Cat()); //Won't compile: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Animal to Cat
    }
}
```

Here the `changeExtendedAnimal()` method uses extends, and therefore the compiler knows that you will get a `Cat` back if you call the method with a `Cat`.
With the `changeAnimal()` method on the other hand, the compiler can't know this and you get a compile time error.